# Copying the Contents of a boost::shared_ptr - is there a way?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I want to copy the contents of a boost::shared_ptr I'm getting in a function

```
void virtual Add(const T_Value& value)
    {           
        push_back(value);
        if (_limit != -1 && int(size()) > _limit)
            erase(begin());//,begin() + (_limit >> 1));
    }
```

Where T_Value is `boost::shared_ptr<ValueType>`

My problem is that with this method, obviously, the use_count of the `value` is incremented because it now has another reference within the std::list this function is part of.

What I want, to do, however, is only copy the contents of `value` into a new shared_ptr, one with a new count, and insert it into the list.

Thus, the use_count - at the end of the function (leaving the scope) would remain the original use_count of `value` for `value`; and a use_count of 1 for the new shared_ptr that will be inserted into the list.

Comment: If your `ValueType` has a copy constructor then construct a `new` value using the existing value (preferably through `make_shared`) and hold on to the resulting pointer in your `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

You can clone a shared pointer with `make_shared`:

```
push_back(boost::make_shared<decltype(*value)>(*value));
```

On C++03:

```
push_back(boost::make_shared<typename T_Value::element_type>(*value));
```

Comment: Will that not increment the use_count of the original value?

Comment: @Cypher_CS: No, it creates a new object by copying `*value`, and a new (currently unshared) pointer to that. Watch out for slicing, though, if the pointer is to a base class.

Comment: Did the second one - but it gives me a `error C2664: 'std::list<_Ty>::push_back' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<T> &'`

Comment: I can't get to element_type for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: @ecatmur
What am I missing?

Comment: @Cypher_CS not sure - `element_type` is definitely a member, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Members

Comment: @ecatmur yeah, I saw it too. But it won't allow me to access it. I guess I'll try some other combinations instead of T_Value.